# ExpandoObject contains no public properties only in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, expandoobject

I am trying to deserialize my JSON object and pass it as a model to my view.  Since I don't know what properties the model will have, I have read that I should use an ExpandoObject.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myObj = new object();

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> container = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    {
        new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Text", "Hello world" } }
    };
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    myObj = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(json_serializer.Serialize(container));
    return View(myObj.ToExpando());
}
```

And, in the same namespace I have defined this class:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(anonymousObject);
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
            expando.Add(item);
        return (ExpandoObject)expando;
    }
}
```

And, in my view I have this loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.Text
}
```

When I run, I get this error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Text'

Upon debugging, the Model doesn't seem to have any public properties.  When I look deep within the private members, I see the data that I want.

Why aren't these public properties such that I can access them?

**Edit:** Here you can see the expando object model that is getting passed to my view:

[image]

**Note:** The `SyncRoot` property seems to contain my object.

**Edit:** This is the deserialized object:

[image]

Comment: I did this with VS2013 and I do get the same result.  But in this case the problem has nothing to do with ExpandoObject, but has to do with the json deserialization.  If you look at "assignees" in your example, it is an array of objects.  The properties on an array of objects are Length, LongLength, Rank, SyncRoot, etc.. So naturally that is what you get in the ExpandoObject.  If you use your ToExpando() method on a more normal object it works fine.  For example: var pet = new { Type = "Dog", Name = "Barkie", Age = 6 }; pet.ToExpando() gives you 3 properties: Type, Name, and Age.

Comment: @MobyDisk thanks for testing in VS2013. However, as shown in my most recent update, the deserialized object is just a simple list of three objects.  The extra properties (Length, LongLength, etc.) don't get added until I convert it to an ExpandoObject.  How can I just send the stuff that I want (the contents of `obj` in my most recent update)?  Basically, I think I need a recursive ExpandoObject.  I am googling now...

Comment: The screen shot shows you expanded the properties of myObj[0].  But the code doesn't call myObj[0].ToExpando, it calls myObj.ToExpando().  That screen shot shows 3 objects.  Are you trying to make an expando of the properties of one object, or the properties of 3 objects?

Comment: I am trying to simply return all of my objects to my view without having to strongly type them.  I have a solution, I will add it as an answer, however, it doesn't solve for deeply nested json objects.

Comment: Ahh I get it.  A recursive Expando.  Hmmm... I will be hanging out in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58493/expando for a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to do something like this (using the ExpandoObjectConverter):

```
var myObj = new object();

List<Dictionary<string, object>> container = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
{
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Text", "Hello world" } }
};
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>>(json_serializer.Serialize(container), converter);

return View(obj);
```

However, this doesn't account for deeply nested JSON objects.  I can probably create some sort of recursive method.

It's sad that the framework doesn't support such an obvious requirement; unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `@item` is defined as a `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair` based on your error.

These means that you have two properties: *Key* and *Value*.

Here are two possible solution:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Values)
{
    @item.Id
}
```

or

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.Value.Id
}
```

Comment: The error I get now is `'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Values'`

Comment: Did you try the second option?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work because the items it loops through are not what I have sent to the model.  It loops through "Length, LongLength, Rank, item"  I tried changing to `@foreach (var item in Model.item)` but it just says `'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'item'`

Comment: I have updated my question with a verbatim reproducible example.

Comment: I tested this with one of my MVC test apps using the and it worked.  I can iterate through the ExpandoObject just fine.  I did have to remove the @model declaration at the top of my .cshtml file though, otherwise it complained the Model wasn't the right type.

Comment: Your update still has the same problem.  It has to be "@item.Value.something".  Put a breakpoint on the @item.Text line and play in the watch window.

Comment: @MobyDisk Are you using MVC 5?  I tried your suggestions and `@item.Value.Text` is null.  `@item.Value` is `1`.  The key of `@item` is `Length`.

Comment: @MobyDisk I have updated the question with a screenshot of what I see.